# Python Fabric Task Doesn't Set Variable?

Tags: python, fabric

I'm not sure why this is happening but in fabric when I try and set a variable like this:

```
@task
def deploy_small_ec2_ami(name):
    a = local("/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -w secret -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net' -b 'dc=example,dc=net' -h ldap-01  -LLL 'cn=%s'" %(name))
    if a:
        sys.exit(1)
```

No matter what the variable 'a' is never set even if the name exists in ldap so the exit never take effect. I have tried to add 'print a' and I don't see anything either, but I know the command works because I get output as follows (host that does exist in ldap):

```
user:~/Projects/fabtask$ fab deploy_small_ec2_ami:bob,ldap
[localhost] local: /usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -w secret -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net' -b 'dc=example,dc=net' -h ldap-01  -LLL 'cn=bob'
dn: cn=bob,ou=hosts,dc=example,dc=net
cn: bob
environment: production
ipHostNumber:
objectClass: device
objectClass: ipHost
objectClass: puppetClient
objectClass: top
puppetClass: cassandra
```

I use var = local('some_command') in other scripts and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a `capture=True` on your `local()` call; that seems to be necessary to capture the output of your command. Otherwise `local()` always returns `None`, which evaluates to `False` in an `if` statement. See [docs here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.local).